# Hashmap in Spring form

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, spring-el

I use the following input tag where entry is an entry of myMap.

```
<form:input path="myMap[${entry.key}].parameters[${counter}].value" />
```

and following objects

```
Map<Long, MyViewModel> myMap;

public class MyViewModel {
private List<My2ViewModel> parameters;
...
```

If the value of entry.key is an integer, everything works prefectly. But if it is a long (ex. 5000000000) it crashes

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1035E:(pos 14): The value '5000000000' cannot be parsed as an int
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Literal.getIntLiteral(Literal.java:79)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatLiteral(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:688)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatStartNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:429)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPrimaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:282)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatUnaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:275)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5000000000"
```

When I add an L (suggestion of Stephen), I get an other error.

```
<form:input path="myMap[${entry.key}L].parameters[${counter}].value" />

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field type is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.<init>(ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.findSpringConvertingPropertyEditor(BindingModel.java:277)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.BindingModel.findEditor(BindingModel.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
...
```

Comment: any chance, Number is converted to exponential format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number `5,000,000,000` is larger than the largest possible value for a Java `int`.  Now it looks like you actually want an `long` value, but unfortunately the Spring documentation says this:

> *"The types of literal expressions supported are strings, dates, numeric values (int, real, and hex), boolean and null."*

No mention of `long`.

Reference: [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) - specifically section 6.5.1.

---

You might "get lucky" by using the Java syntax for a `long` literal - `5000000000L` - but I doubt that it will work.